# Using MS-PL licensed library for internal company use

Tags: licensing, legal, ms-pl

I want to use a [MS-PL licensed](http://opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL) library in a proprietary software, but it'll run inside my company, with no external distribution.

Does the license allows this kind of usage or it constitutes a violation of the license?

Comment: The MS-PL license doesn't appear to restrict your commercial use of the software, even if you do distribute.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal advice is off topic on Programmers. See: [When is a software licensing question on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/88986)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MS-PL](http://opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL):

> 1. Definitions
>
> The terms "reproduce," "reproduction," "derivative works," and "distribution" have the same meaning here as under U.S. copyright law.

This then directly goes to the copyright law.  From [bitlaw](http://www.bitlaw.com/copyright/scope.html):

> The distribution right grants to the copyright holder the exclusive right to make a work available to the public by sale, rental, lease, or lending.

Or the more wordy text [Title 17 USC § 106 (3)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106)

> Subject to sections 107 through 122, the owner of copyright under this title has the exclusive rights to do and to authorize any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> (3) to distribute copies or phono records of the copyrighted work to the public by sale or other transfer of ownership, or by rental, lease, or lending;

Again, note the 'to the public' in there.

As described in the original poster's question:

> but it'll run inside my company, with no external distribution.

This is not to the public and does not constitute distribution of the work.

That said, I am not a lawyer, and thus if you have specific issue with this you had best contact your company lawyer to get an authoritative answer.